# What is the pattern to appear in the box?

Tags: pattern

I was puzzled by the pattern sequence in the following picture. What is the pattern to show up in the box? This is a question from a primary school workbook for selective high examinations in Sydney.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: interestingly, there is a pattern of 4, 8, 12 in the amount of line segments that make up the figures. However none of the options have 16.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who has come in to join in the crack of the puzzle. All the thoughts put forward here are quite innovative in a way. Personally, I agree with the solution by @Lidaranis because that is the difference which is least arguable so far. Thank you again for your participation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 2. There are no right angles in the sequence, and 2 is the only one without right angles.

Comment: This is more convincing then @K Sharing's answer.

Comment: Yes, agree that +1. And think that it's puzzle for primary school should not to be so complicated.

Answer (score 4):

> The answer should be 2. It is basically w, x, y, and z. However, the letters are a bit modified.

Comment: The third one hardly looks like y...

Comment: look at the two diagonal lines

Comment: Yeah I see it but it seems kinda weak.

Comment: I was thinking the same but it doesnt seem convincing

Comment: I mean you can kind of distort 4 to make it a z

Answer (score 1):

> I believe 2 since the (smaller) angle between any two intersecting lines should be the same in all figures (45 degrees).

Comment: The third image in the sequence has 60-degree angles